# how to validate whether given URL is domain or sub domain or exact page using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, url

I want to check whether user given URL is  domain or sub domain or exact page. Can anybody help me with the regex or let me know if there are any other methods?

```
i want this result:

input:'www.google.com'
ouput: 'root domain'

input:'drive.google.com'
output: 'sub domain'

input: 'www.google.com/asdasdas'
output:'page'
```

Comment: https://regexr.com

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear your requirement, whether the URLs having a protocol such as 'http//' and 'https//', but you can use the following function with out regex, if the requirement as mention above.

```
url = 'drive.google.com'

def typeOfURL(url):
    if len(url.split('/')) >= 2 :
        return 'page'
    elif url.split('.')[0] == 'www':
        return 'root domain'
    else:
        return 'sub domain'
        
print(typeOfURL(url))
```

Comment: it may be http or https, but what happens if user inputs 'www.google.co.uk'?

Comment: sorry to ask again, how to get output if link is just "google.com' or "https://google.com"?